# Doubly Linked List - cannot in delete the first Node

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

```
 struct Node
{
int data;
Node *next;
Node *prev;
};

class DoublyLinkedList
{
ofstream cout3;
Node *head; 
public:
DoublyLinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    cout3.open("task3.out");
}

void insert(int num)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    //To insert if there are no elements
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        head = temp;
    }
    //To insert if there are elements
    else
    {
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = head;
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    }       
    cout3<<"inserted "<<num<<endl;      
}

void dele(int num)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    int found_num = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == num)
        {
            found_num = 1;
            break;
        }   
        else
            temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(found_num == 0)
        cout3<<"cannot delete "<<num<<endl;
    //To delete first element
    else if (temp->prev == NULL)
    {
        head = temp->next;
        (temp->next)->prev == NULL;
        delete temp;            
        cout3<<"deleted "<<num<<endl;
    }
    //To delete last element
    else if (temp->next == NULL)
    {
        (temp->prev)->next = NULL;
        cout3<<"deleted "<<num<<endl;
        delete temp;
    }
    //To delete any other element
    else
    {
        (temp->prev)->next = temp->next;
        (temp->next)->prev = temp->prev;
        cout3<<"deleted "<<num<<endl;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void search(int num)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    int found_num = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == num)
        {
            found_num = 1;
            break;
        }   
        else
            temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(found_num == 0)
        cout3<<"not found "<<num<<endl;
    else
        cout3<<"found "<<num<<endl;
}

void display()
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout3<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout3<<endl;
}
};
```

My implementation of Doubly Linked List.
I only insert at the beginning and delete the first occurrence of the number.
However if I want to delete the first element then it prints "deleted *number*" but when i display the number is still there.
Problem seems to be in my delete function but I cannot find what it is

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], it's required to make your question on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expend the code to test it, it will give out the warning. Fix it, then the program will function as expected.

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp:66:30: warning: equality comparison result unused
      [-Wunused-comparison]
          (temp->next)->prev == NULL;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
test.cpp:66:30: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an
      assignment
          (temp->next)->prev == NULL;
                             ^~
                             =
1 warning generated.
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
};

class DoublyLinkedList
{
  std::ofstream cout3;
  Node *head; 

public:
  DoublyLinkedList()
  {
      head = NULL;
      cout3.open("task3.out");
  }

  void insert(int num)
  {
      Node *temp = new Node;
      //To insert if there are no elements
      if(head == NULL)
      {
          temp->prev = NULL;
          temp->data = num;
          temp->next = NULL;
          head = temp;
      }
      //To insert if there are elements
      else
      {
          temp->prev = NULL;
          temp->data = num;
          temp->next = head;
          head->prev = temp;
          head = temp;
      }       
      cout3<<"inserted "<<num<<std::endl;      
  }

  void dele(int num)
  {
      Node *temp = head;
      int found_num = 0;
      while(temp != NULL)
      {
          if(temp->data == num)
          {
              found_num = 1;
              break;
          }   
          else
              temp = temp->next;
      }
      if(found_num == 0)
          cout3<<"cannot delete "<<num<<std::endl;
      //To delete first element
      else if (temp->prev == NULL)
      {
          head = temp->next;
          (temp->next)->prev == NULL;
          delete temp;            
          cout3<<"deleted "<<num<<std::endl;
      }
      //To delete last element
      else if (temp->next == NULL)
      {
          (temp->prev)->next = NULL;
          cout3<<"deleted "<<num<<std::endl;
          delete temp;
      }
      //To delete any other element
      else
      {
          (temp->prev)->next = temp->next;
          (temp->next)->prev = temp->prev;
          cout3<<"deleted "<<num<<std::endl;
          delete temp;
      }
  }

  void search(int num)
  {
      Node *temp = head;
      int found_num = 0;
      while(temp != NULL)
      {
          if(temp->data == num)
          {
              found_num = 1;
              break;
          }   
          else
              temp = temp->next;
      }
      if(found_num == 0)
          cout3<<"not found "<<num<<std::endl;
      else
          cout3<<"found "<<num<<std::endl;
  }

  void display()
  {
      Node *temp = head;
      while(temp != NULL)
      {
          cout3<<temp->data<<" ";
          temp = temp->next;
      }
      cout3<<std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
   DoublyLinkedList list;
   list.insert(3);
   list.insert(4);
   list.insert(5);
   list.display();

   list.dele(3);
   list.display();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it does not generate a warning when I compile. My compiler version is gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)

Comment: @AkshatKarani, maybe my compiler(`Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)`) gives out the warning by default. For gcc/g++ under linux , you need to open the warning option(**-Wall**) explicitly. See the trials in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f595b25c3b2c335

Answer (score 3):

See this line:   (temp->next)->prev == NULL;
You wrote == instead of = , this seems to be the problem.
You dont show how you print the value but im guessing you move backward untill null value before you start..

Answer (score -3):

In below link there is a guide to free the memory. `Delete` function not work mostly you can `free` method.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-delete-a-linked-list/

Comment: Delete is basicly a wrapper for free(), and it's working as it should..

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz `delete`is **not** a wrapper for `free`. The two **must not** be used interchangeably.

Comment: @Max Vollmer Delete is a wrapper for free and free() can be used instead, the difference is that free don't initialize the class d'tor.

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz Please don't spread this half-truth. While it may be that there are implementations of the language that implement `delete` as a wrapper of `free`, that is not defined by the language standard and thus should not be relied on in any way. In fact using `delete` for memory allocated with `malloc` or `free` on memory allocated with `new` is UB.

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz • mixing `delete` and `free()` on my system crashes the application.  Because they are in separately managed heaps.

Comment: @Max Vollmer show me a single compiler that dont treat delete as free + destructor..

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz Even if you're 100% sure all compilers your project will ever be compiled with behave in that way, there is no guarantee this won't change in the future. And what Eljay writes is correct: The standard only requires `malloc` to use the heap. Also both the `new` and `delete` operators can be overloaded. It's really bad to argue against this with compiler implementation details that are not part of the standard. I strongly recommend you read `Secure Coding in C and C++` by Robert Seacord and `Effective C++` by Scott Meyers, especially since you teach this stuff at a college.